# Optimizing a single file in a premake-generated VS solution

Tags: premake

I have a project which contains a rather performance-critical file, and to make debugging of the rest of the program feasible, it has to be compiled with at least some optimizations, in particular inlining. I used to do this manually in VS2010, but now I would like to achieve the same in my VS2015 projects generated by premake5.

I understand that I should have a `configuration` block for this file somewhat looking like this:

```
filter { "configurations:Debug*" }
  configuration "critical_file.cpp"
    -- Optimization settings go here
  configuration {}
filter {}
```

I have tried various things: `optimize "Speed"` or `optimize "Full"` does not work because VS2015 assumes **/RTC1**, which is incompatible with **/O2** or **/O4**:

```
7>cl : Command line error D8016: '/Ox' and '/RTC1' command-line options are incompatible
```

Adding `flags { "NoRuntimeChecks" }` in this block makes no difference.

I also tried adding `inlining "auto"` instead to at least enable function inlining, but that didn't generate any specific configuration for this file.

I guess what I want in the end looks somewhat like this:

```
<ClCompile Include="critical_file.cpp">
  <Optimization Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">Full</Optimization>
  <BasicRuntimeChecks Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'"></BasicRuntimeChecks>
</ClCompile>
```

Is this possible with premake at all, or will it need to be patched to automatically disable basic run-time checks for any configuration or files with optimization?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
project "MyProject"
    flags "NoRuntimeChecks"

    filter { "files:critical_file.cpp" }
       optimize "Speed"
```

If you want to optimize the debug and release versions separately, it would look like:

```
project "MyProject"
    flags "NoRuntimeChecks"

    filter { "configurations:Debug", "files:critical_file.cpp" }
       optimize "Speed"

    filter { "configurations:Release", "files:critical_file.cpp" }
       optimize "Full"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sadly that doesn't seem to be quite what I'm after, as I do not want to give up Visual Studio's debugging helpers in Debug mode and actually keep runtime checks enabled for the project, but disable them for that specific file. What I want to achieve **is** possible with manually created VS project files, as shown in the last example in my initial post. Building the file will emit a warning but it does actually optimize that single file. I think the main problem is that adding ```flags { "NoRuntimeChecks" }``` in a filter block for a single file does not generate a project like in my example.